# Single linked list in Python, how to write pop and push?

Tags: python, stack

I am trying to code a class that makes use of Push and Pop from a stack (with single linked list). I am not sure how to write the push and pop functions. I really need a simple example written in Python with the following functions.

```
Push
Pop
ifEmpty
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280243/python-linked-list Second result on Google.

Comment: Why use a linked list? Python's built-in lists are perfect for this.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks) that Dyno Fu linked to:

> The list methods make it very easy to
>   use a list as a stack, where the last
>   element added is the first element
>   retrieved (“last-in, first-out”). To
>   add an item to the top of the stack,
>   use `append()`. To retrieve an item from
>   the top of the stack, use `pop()`
>   without an explicit index. For
>   example:

```
>>> stack = [3, 4, 5]
>>> stack.append(6)
>>> stack.append(7)
>>> stack
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> stack.pop()
7
>>> stack
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> stack.pop()
6
>>> stack.pop()
5
>>> stack
[3, 4]
```

And finally, to [check if a list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/python-what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty):

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> not my_list
True
```

Answer (score 3):

And here is the simplest stack class:

```
class stack(list):
    def push(self,item):
        self.append(item)
    def isEmpty(self):
        return not self

>>> a = stack()
>>> a.push(1)
>> a.isEmpty()
False
>>> a.pop()
1
>>> a.isEmpty()
True
```