# Traversing a deque in python?

Tags: python

It must be possible to traverse a list removing elements and adding some new to the begining in an efficient fashion. In C I would use a linked list,

Comment: Do you mean [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque)?

Comment: Yes - it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I mean collections.deque. I want go through it element delete some and add occasionally some to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples of LinkedList implementations in Python. I came across a good one in SO a while back... [Python Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280243/python-linked-list). If you scroll down a bit, some other users have some good implementations to follow.

Comment: That's assuming you want to stick to a LinkedList. But of course, your question is very broad, you can find a different way as well.

Comment: `deque` has the performance characteristics of a linked list.

Comment: Deque is almost what I was looking for, but how can you traverse it, with a sort of iterator. I have to perfom a complex calculation before I decide to keep an element.