# Numpy concatenate is slow: any alternative approach?

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy, concatenation

I am running the following code:

```
for i in range(1000)
    My_Array=numpy.concatenate((My_Array,New_Rows[i]), axis=0)
```

The above code is slow. Is there any faster approach?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is basically what is happening in all algorithms based on arrays.

Each time you change the size of the array, it needs to be resized and every element needs to be copied. This is happening here too. (some implementations reserve some empty slots; e.g. doubling space of internal memory with each growing).

- If you got your data at np.array creation-time, just add these all at once (memory will allocated only once then!)
- If not, collect them with something like a linked list (allowing O(1) appending-operations). Then read it in your np.array at once (again only one memory allocation).

This is not much of a numpy-specific topic, but much more about data-strucures.

**Edit:** as this quite vague answer got some upvotes, i feel the need to make clear that my linked-list approach is one possible example. As indicated in the comment, python's lists are more array-like (and definitely not linked-lists). But the core-fact is: list.append() in python is [fast](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) (amortized: O(1)) while that's not true for numpy-arrays! There is also a small part about the internals in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented):

> > How are lists implemented?
> >
> > **Python’s lists are really variable-length arrays, not Lisp-style linked lists**. The **implementation uses a contiguous array of references to other objects**, and keeps a pointer to this array and the array’s length in a list head structure.
> >
> > This makes indexing a list a[i] an operation whose cost is independent of the size of the list or the value of the index.
> >
> > When items are appended or inserted, the array of references is resized. **Some cleverness is applied to improve the performance of appending items repeatedly**; when the array must be grown, some extra space is allocated so the next few times don’t require an actual resize.

(bold annotations by me)

Comment: I actually used the list appending and the performance is substantially boosted up.

Comment: Keep in mind, that pythons ```list``` is actually an array (internally). It surely will do some tricks like reserving empty slots while growing and has good amortized complexity, but a classic linked-list could be even faster (depending on many factors).

Comment: Python doesn't have a native linked list class.

Comment: How would you do a real linked-list in python? No built-in? Only things like this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_linked_lists.htm?

Comment: There's deque from collections module, which is faster than lists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668769/does-python-have-built-in-linkedlist-data-structure

Answer (score 15):

Maybe creating an empty array with the correct size and than populating it? 
if you have a list of arrays with same dimensions you could

```
import numpy as np 
arr = np.zeros((len(l),)+l[0].shape) 
for i, v in enumerate(l):
   arr[i] = v
```

works much faster for me, it only requires one memory allocation

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what  `New_Rows[i]` is, and what kind of array do you want.  If you start with lists (or 1d arrays) that you want to join end to end (to make a long 1d array) just concatenate them all at once.  Concatenate takes a list of any length, not just 2 items.

```
 np.concatenate(New_Rows, axis=0)
```

or maybe use an intermediate list comprehension (for more flexibility)

```
 np.concatenate([row for row in New_Rows])
```

or closer to your example.

```
 np.concatenate([New_Rows[i] for i in range(1000)])
```

But if `New_Rows` elements are all the same length, and you want a 2d array, one `New_Rows` value per row, `np.array` does a nice job:

```
 np.array(New_Rows)
 np.array([i for i in New_Rows])
 np.array([New_Rows[i] for i in range(1000)])
```

`np.array` is designed primarily to build an array from a list of lists.

`np.concatenate` can also build in 2d, but the inputs need to be 2d to start with.  `vstack` and `stack` can take care of that.  But all those `stack` functions use some sort of list comprehension followed by `concatenate`.

In general it is better/faster to iterate or append with lists, and apply the `np.array` (or concatenate) just once.  `appending` to a list is fast; much faster than making a new array.

Answer (score 1):

I think @thebeancounter 's solution is the way to go.
If you do not know the exact size of your numpy array ahead of time, you can also take an approach similar to how vector class is implemented in C++.

To be more specific, you can wrap the numpy ndarray into a new class which has a default size which is larger than your current needs. When the numpy array is almost fully populated, copy the current array to a larger one.

Answer (score -1):

Assume you have a large list of 2D numpy arrays, with the same number of columns and different number of rows like this :

x = [numpy_array1(r_1, c),......,numpy_arrayN(r_n, c)]

concatenate like this:

```
while len(x) != 1:
    if len(x) == 2:
        x = np.concatenate((x[0], x[1]))
        break
    for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
        if (i+1) == len(x):
            x[0] = np.concatenate((x[0], x[i]))
        else:
            x[i] = np.concatenate((x[i], x[i+1]))

    x = x[::2]
```

Comment: I ran this using `x = [np.zeros(2000) for _ in range(1000)]`.  This runs in about 50ms.  `np.concatenate(x)` (see @hpaulj's answer) runs in 2ms.  Your answer is certainly faster than the method given in the question, but much slower than the best practices for numpy.

Comment: It really is a clever way to merge pairs of arrays in the minimum number of operations, but concatenate accepts lists of any length so you aren't limited to pairs.

Comment: I never claimed this to be the optimal pythonic solution, it just works and is simple. and I used pairs of 2, because every new memory allocation for concatenation would be bare minimum. my pc got stuck when i first ran the np.concatenate sequentially , I did this and it worked for me, so I felt like sharing it since I couldn't find any answer for my situation at that time.maybe I should have searched more.

Comment: Pre-allocating the np.empty array is the way to go. It runs about 100X faster for me in the case of collecting a lot of randomly sized data packets of [N,5] that need to then be saved as a single vertically stacked array. Of course this assumes you have the RAM to hold everything.