# Most computationally efficient way to get average of particular pairs of rows, and concatenate all of the results with a particular row

Tags: arrays, numpy, performance

I have a sample array

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [
     [1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9],
     [10, 11, 12],
     [13, 14, 15],
    ]
)
```

And an array of indices for which I would like to get averages from

```
b = np.array([[1,3], [1,2], [2,3]])
```

In addition, I need the final result to have the first row concatenated to each of these averages

I can get the desired result using this

```
np.concatenate( (np.tile(a[0],(3,1)), a[b].mean(1)), axis=1)
```

```
array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  7. ,  8. ,  9. ],
       [ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  5.5,  6.5,  7.5],
       [ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  8.5,  9.5, 10.5]])
```

I am wondering if there is a more computationally efficient way, as I've heard concatenate is slow

[Numpy concatenate is slow: any alternative approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470264/numpy-concatenate-is-slow-any-alternative-approach)

I'm thinking there might be a way with a combinatin of advanced indexing, `.mean()`, and reshape, but I am not able to come up with anything that gives the desired array.

Comment: Note that numpy concatenation is especially slow if you do it one-by-one inside a loop, as the array needs to be resized constantly. This doesn't seem to be the case here. What are the sizes of the arrays you are dealing with?

Comment: 24x512x1024 floats. This is for matching learning training, so will end up with around 100,000 of these operations. But it's a new array every operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that `concatenate` is slow. In fact, it is not so slow. The problem is to use it in a loop so to produce a **growing array**. This pattern is very inefficient because it produces many temporary array and copies. However, in your case you do not use such a pattern so this is fine. Here, `concatenate` is properly used and perfectly match with your intent. You could create an array and fill the left and the right part separately, but this is what `concatenate` should do in the end. That being said, **`concatenate` has a quite big overhead mainly for small arrays** (like most Numpy functions) because of many internal checks** (so to adapt its behaviour regarding the shape of the input arrays). Moreover, the **implicit casting** from `np.int_` to `np.float64` of `np.tile(a[0],(3,1))` introduces another overhead. Moreover, note that `mean` is *not very optimized for such a case*. It is faster to use `(a[b[:,0]] + a[b[:,1]]) * 0.5` although the intent is less clear.

```py
n, m = a.shape[1], b.shape[0]
res = np.empty((n, m*2), dtype=np.float64)
res[:,m] = a[0]                            # Note: implicit conversion done here
res[:,m:] = (a[b[:,0]] + a[b[:,1]]) * 0.5  # Also here
```

The resulting operation is about **3 times faster** on my machine with your example. It may not be the case for big input arrays (although I expect a speed up too).

For big arrays, the best solution is to use a **Numba** (or Cython) code with loops so to avoid the creation/filling of big expensive **temporary arrays**. Numba should also speed up the computation of small arrays because it mostly removes the overhead of Numpy functions (I expect a speed up of about 5x-10x here).

Comment: Is there a point where if the arrays are large enough, concatenation would be the faster choice? If it helps, I am working with 24x512x1024 floats

Comment: What type case would `mean` be optimized for?

Comment: One has to test for bigger array but I expect `concatenate` to be a bit slower on big arrays or eventually equally fast because of the RAM throughput being saturated (though temporary array make both codes sub-optimal). `mean` is optimized for 2 cases: the computation of the mean of contiguous lines along the last contiguous axis OR the computation of the mean of many long contiguous lines along a non-contiguous axis.

Comment: I'm still a bit hazy on when to use mean so I made a followup question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191923/cases-where-numpy-mean-is-more-computationally-efficient-vs-executing-the-math