# Why is a doubly-linked-list used in a music player with “next” and “previous” buttons while using list is simpler?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am learning about linked lists on Codecademy and there is an instruction saying that

> Before moving on, take a moment to think about doubly-linked lists.
> What do you think are some possible real-life uses?

with some uses

- A music player with “next” and “previous” buttons
- An app that shows you where your subway is on the train line
- The “undo” and “redo” functionality in a web browser

---

Would it be simpler to use a list?

What are the benefits of using a linked list to perform these tasks?

For instance, using a list for a music player next and previous buttons

```
counter = 0
playlist = ['song', 'song2', 'song3', 'song4']
current_song = playlist[counter]
next_song = playlist[min(counter+1, len(playlist)-1]
```

Comment: in python a list would probably do fine also in python there is a built-in method `next` (tho there is a slight issue with using sth like that to go back https://stackoverflow.com/a/44612066/14531062)

Comment: Hiya, I'm not sure about the Python details but generally it might be more about the efficiency of the underlying implementation - in some languages eg Java, there are different implementations of List, which present the same interface to client code but work differently under the covers. Conceptually in such a case, you can see how an implementation that links elements  to neighbours would potentially be a good fit for any use case where navigating to next or previous is important

Comment: Your question seems like a general algorithmic/data structure question. Why did you use the Python tag?

Comment: @Olivier I'm learning this algorithm in Python, therefore I think the answers would be more precise by including the Python tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an algorithmic point of view, there are different *sequence container* types:

- static arrays

  It is the most simple possible container with a static (maximum) size and direct access (through a numeric index)
- dynamic arrays

  You still have direct access with a numeric index, but the size can arbitrary grow (limited by available memory). Python *lists* actually fall here. The downside is that they can require a full reallocation and copy when they reach the allocated size. Removing elements is also a costly operation
- singly linked lists

  adding and removing elements at the head side is easy, as is inserting a new element (or removing one) after an already found other one. You can only scan them in one direction, and finding an element knowing its position is rather lengthy (no direct access). It has an overhead of one index per node
- doubly linked lists

  when compared to singly linked lists, you can scan them in both direction and inserting (or removing) before an element is easy. No direct access either and the overhead is two index per node

Dynamic arrays are the *multi-purpose work horse* in most languages, and are the standard Python lists. With few additions and removal they offer both ease of use and correct performances. But other containers do have use cases. For example a fifo queue could be easily implemented as a singly linked list.

I agree on one point: music player with prev and next button *on a know list of elements* could be implemented as an array (what a Python list is). But an undo/redo functionality with a limited depth is an excellent use case for a doubly linked list:

- you want to be able to remove on both side (once depth has been reached, every addition has to drop the oldest element)
- you only need to go one step (on any direction) from one element

Answer (score 2):

Linked list consumes limited memory, where doubly linked list possible to allocate more memory if you have more data. Linked list will keep refernence of next element, where doubly linked list will keep reference of previous and next element.

[image]

Since doubly linked list have reference to both side, memory consumption is more but more efficient to access elements (reverse iteration as well (BACK/NEXT))

> Reference means - Address of next / previous element

Undo and Redo - I believe, it simply need a linked list because it requires only less memory and insert and delete operation from one side ***for simple task***

Please refer [Dictionary best data structure for train routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534438/dictionary-best-data-structure-for-train-routes) to know about *"An app that shows you where your subway is on the train line"*

The time complexity of removal and insertion is O(1) but searching is O(n)

Please refer to know about time complexity https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/php-7-data/9781786463890/c5319c42-c462-43a1-b33d-d683f3ef7e35.xhtml

Please refer to know more about linked list in python [Does python have built-in linkedList data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668769/does-python-have-built-in-linkedlist-data-structure)

Answer (score 1):

From the Official [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented)

> Python’s lists are really variable-length arrays, not Lisp-style linked lists. The implementation uses a contiguous array of references to other objects, and keeps a pointer to this array and the array’s length in a list head structure.
> This makes indexing a list a[i] an operation whose cost is independent of the size of the list or the value of the index.
> When items are appended or inserted, the array of references is resized. Some cleverness is applied to improve the performance of appending items repeatedly; when the array must be grown, some extra space is allocated so the next few times don’t require an actual resize.

So, python lists are nothing but variable length arrays. I dug into [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Include/listobject.h#l23) of cpython, and on expanding the macro, the basic structure is defined as:

```
typedef struct { 
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD 
    PyObject **ob_item; 
    Py_ssize_t allocated; 
} PyListObject;
```

**Coming to the reason why they chose a Doubly Linked List:**

• Skip Back/Forward- Because each node in a double linked list has a pointer the previous and next node, it is easy to implement skip forward/backward functionality.

• Play Next Track- The pointer to the next node also makes it quite easy to start the next track when a track is over.

• Append When you add a new track to a playlist, you tack it on to the end. In a linked list, adding a new element is constant time — O(1) operation. Note that as the songs are read in from a data source and added to the play list, this will be done as a sequence of calls to append.

• Beginning/End- Finally, because a linked list has head and tail properties, this provides for an easy way to delineate the beginning and end of a playlist

Answer (score 1):

In my experience programming in many different problem domains, there is *almost never* a reason to use a linked list, whether singly or doubly linked.

The theoretical advantage is that a linked list supports O(1) insertion and removal at arbitrary positions in the list. But on today's hardware, you need a pretty large list (thousands to tens of thousands of items) *and* you need to be doing very frequent insertion and removal operations before this advantage really starts to matter in practice.