# Accessing item in a nested list: creating dependency between items, saving memory

Tags: python

I need to keep track of some process which goes like this

```
time0 = [  [0]  ]  
time1 = [  [ time0 ] , [1]  ]  
time2 = [  [ time1 ] , [2]  ]  
time3 = [  [ time2 ] , [3]  ]  
...
time5 = [  [ time4 ] , [5]  ]
```

I do like this because:
- I need the inner objects, in a `time5` object, to be dependent, so that if I modify `time0`, all `time1` to `time5` see the change;
- I create a million of those `time5` objects, and my guess is that the previous process will be easy on memory;

Now, I have a hard time to access the inner element of `time5`.
I would hard code

```
time5[0][0][0][0][0][0] = 0   
time5[0][0][0][0][1][0] = 1  
time5[0][0][0][1][0] = 2  
time5[0][0][1][0] = 3
time5[0][1][0] = 4
time5[1][0] = 5
```

but I need a function which will produce those index `[0][0][1][0]`, for any arbitrary `timeX` object.
I don't see how to do that.

I'm also open to any design suggestion.
I suspect my idea is not the best.

Comment: you clearly want to use an Linked-List : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280243/python-linked-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First here's the solution you are looking for (I guess):

```
def access(time_object, max_lvl, lvl):
    tmp = time_object
    while(lvl < max_lvl):
        tmp = time_object[0]
    return tmp
```

Now to be honest, I don't see why you don't simply store every element in an array. The reason why you don't need to go with your complicated approach is that it seems that the dependency relation is sequential: timeN = [ [ timeN-1 ], [N] ]

let's say you put every time object in a list [ time1, time2, ...., timeN] you can easily see that

```
timeN[0][0][0][0][1][0] = list[N-4][0]
```