# Is there a linked list predefined library in Python?

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I know in c++ it already exist

  `#include <list>`

Now I am curious to know if it exist in python also.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you elaborate why you need this? Python already has the `list` type.

Comment: A Python `list` is equivalent to an array, not a linked list, it's a different data type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280243/python-linked-list

Comment: This question should be reopened - it's clear what the user is asking for. As @Leigh mentioned, a list in Python is something very different from a linked list. Maybe it's a duplicate, but the close reason given is wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can also take a look at [`llist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/llist/) python package, which provides some useful features that `deque` does not. There are not only doubly linked lists, but also single linked lists data structure in that package. IMHO, one of the biggest advantages of this package is the ability to store a reference to the llist elements.

Comment: There's another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280243/python-linked-list?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -2):

It appears that [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is a doubly-linked-list library in Python. According to the documentation, it should have approximately O(1) cost when appending or popping from the head or the tail, as well as O(n) for regular inserts (which matches what we'd expect from a linked list).

API: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/282238/2441252

Comment: I went through the document for deque. It seems like deque is more like a FIFO or LIFO. You cannot insert elements in the middle of the queue. You can only insert them at the beginning or the end.

Comment: @winni2k - only if you don't do something smart, like keep a reference to a particular node that represents a known insertion point. With a doubly linked list, you can get O(1) insertions to intelligently defined points and only pay an O(n) cost of finding those points up front.

Comment: i disagree, insert/remove should be O(1) for a linkedlist given a reference to the element

Comment: @Mugen True for python 2. But for Python 3.5, you can insert element in deque. See: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque.insert

Comment: Linked lists should insert in O(1)

Comment: @Mugen ...isn't that normal behavior for a linked list? You can't insert into the middle without walking to that position.

Comment: @user3932000 But suppose you walk up to that position you should be able to insert right?

Comment: This is untrue, please edit