# Reassigning multiple variables in one line

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm trying to understand some code that [reverses a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529359/reversing-a-linked-list-in-python/22049871#22049871).

Here's how I'm constructing a linked list:

```
class Node:
     def __init__(self, value, next=None):
          self.value = value
          self.next = next

def initialize():
     start = Node(0)
     prev = start
     for i in range(1, 6):
          cur = Node(i)
          prev.next = cur
          prev = cur
     return start
```

Here's the correct code in the answer:

```
def reverse_list(head):
     new_head = None
     while head:
          head.next, head, new_head = new_head, head.next, head 
     return new_head
```

And here's what I have:

```
def reverse_list(head):
     new_head = None
     while head:
          new_head, head, head.next = head, head.next, new_head 
     return new_head
```

However, my code throws an `AttributeError` when reversing a linked list:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I'm using the exactly same replacements as the correct answer, only in a different order. Why does my code throw an error? Does order matter when it comes to one line variable reassignments?

Comment: Just to be clear, does your code work if you change the order to match the sample code?

Comment: Show how to construct a minimal list that will raise the error

Comment: @Blorgbeard yeah, it works if I change the order.

Comment: @MadPhysicist updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `head.next` becomes `None` after the first iteration. Then on the second iteration `head` gets assigned to `head.next` i.e. is set to None before calling `head.next` (on the left side) hence the error. For instance let's have the following scenario:

```
class Spam:

def __init__(self):
    self.foo = 1
    self.bar = 2


spam = Spam()
spam.foo, spam.bar = spam.bar, spam.foo
print(spam.foo, spam.bar) # 2, 1 as expected
```

but when we do:

```
spam.foo, spam, spam.bar = spam.bar, None, spam.foo
```

results in:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 9, in
>   
>       spam.foo, spam, spam.bar = spam.bar, None, spam.foo AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bar'

So to answer your question the order does matter. In fact changing the order of the *toy* example to:

```
spam.foo, spam.bar, spam = spam.bar, spam.foo, None
```

does not throw any exceptions.

Comment: Does Python assign variables like this from left to right, then? I understand this issue, but I still don't understand why the "correct" response (which seems like it should set head.next to None as well) works.

Comment: I would assume so. In the other answer `head.next` gets call before changing the value of `head` therefore is not set to `None` before the calling.

Comment: @DanielQ Updated the answer!