# please can someone get my linked list below to work?, there's an issue

Tags: python-2.7

```
class node:
    def __init__(self):   
        self.value=None
        self.pointer=None

    def setvalue(self,x):
        self.value=x
    def setpointer(self,node):
        self.pointer=node

    def show(self):
        print self.nodes
        print self.value

class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes=[]

    def addnode(self,nodevalue):
        newnode=node()
        newnode.setvalue(nodevalue)
        self.nodes[-1].setpointer(newnode)

    def removenode(self,nodeposition):
        if nodeposition==0:
            self.nodes[1:]
        else:
            self.nodes[0:nodepostion:1]+self.nodes[(nodespostion+1):]

item=linkedlist()
item.addnode(2)
```

Comment: What's the issue specifically?

Comment: Among other things, you access self.nodes in node.print, but you never set self.nodes anywhere else in node. Also, you probably need to `self.nodes.append(newnode)` in linkedlist.addnode(), before you can access self.nodes[-1].

Comment: @Markku_K thank you, so should I put it all under one class?

Comment: You can look at some examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280243/python-linked-list

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use this implementation, python lists are easier.

Try creating a list like you did linkedlist.nodes

```
self.nodes=[]
```

and add to it by

```
nodes.append(nodevalue)
```

When I have executed your code, there is an exception in this line

```
self.nodes[-1].setpointer(newnode)
```

lists have no values at negative indices.

For more information about lists, refer to [tutorials point - python lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)