# How to reduce/optimize memory usage when calculating area of skyline?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate the area of skyline (overlapping rectangles with same baseline)

```
building_count = int(input())
items = {} # dictionary, location on x axis is the key, height is the value
count = 0 # total area
for j in range(building_count):
    line = input().split(' ')
    H = int(line[0]) # height
    L = int(line[1]) # left point (start of the building)
    R = int(line[2]) # right point (end of the building)
    for k in range(R - L):
        if not (L+k in  items): # if it's not there, add it
            items[L+k] = H
        elif H > items[L+k]: # if we have a higher building on that index
            items[L+k] = H
for value in items.values(): # we add each column basically
    count += value
print(count)
```

sample input would be:

```
5
3 -3 0
2 -1 1
4 2 4
2 3 7
3 6 8
```

and output is `29`.

The issue is memory efficiency, when there are lots of values, the script simply throws `MemoryError`. Anyone have some ideas for optimizing memory usage?

Comment: Looks like algorithmics homework

Comment: If it's the dictionary getting large that's causing the memory problem, you could try replacing it with a "shelf" from the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module which will effectively store its contents in a file.

Comment: the input isn't sorted by the left point, it's just a coincidence.

Comment: Is there a limit on the `L`/`R` values? If you have `L=0 and R=10^9` you are going to run out of memory. Is this python2? You can use `xrange` in that case. But you do understand that if `R-L` is large, you will be doing lots and lots of useless iterations and there is a optimal way to do that.

Comment: -10^9 <= L < R <= 1e9 is the limit, H limit is 10^9

Comment: limit for building_count?

Comment: Note wrt to using `shelve`, you can control how much ram it uses for its cache by calling `Shelf.sync()` periodically to flush it since that empties the cache (as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.Shelf.sync).

Comment: limit for building count is 10^5

Comment: Then your approach of creating 10^10 keys in the worst case in the dictionary is wrong. So instead of using a dict, you should use lists. Let's say there is a building with `10 0 100` and another with `20 50 150`, then that list might have info like `[(0, 10), (50, 20), (150, 0)]` which is (height, x_coordinate). Read as between 0 to 50 height is 10, between 50 to 150 height is 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for getting `MemoryError` is huge size of the dictionary being created. In the worst case, the dict can have 10^10 keys, which would end up taking all your memory. If there really is a need, `shelve` is a possible solution to make use of such large dict.

Let's say there is a building with `10 0 100` and another with `20 50 150`, then that list might have info like `[(-10^9, 0), (0, 10), (50, 20), (150, 0), (10^9, 0)]`. As you come across more buildings, you can add more entries in this list. This will be `O(n^2)`.

[This](https://nb4799.neu.edu/wordpress/?p=754) might help you further.

Comment: You can't always get `O(nlogn)`. Best case is `O(1)`. Worst case will always be `O(n^2)`

Comment: For the heap method it is O(N^2), but if we use something similar to merge sort, then it would be `O(nlogn)`

Comment: The issue is not with sorting but with computing the overlaps. If all your buildings overlap, you will have to test and subtract from each one.

Comment: Yeah forgot about that. Agreed!

Comment: Glad we talked that through. I found the O(n) solution. Will write up now.

Comment: Interesting, the list is not pre-sorted, if the list is sorted then you can probably do it in `O(n)`. Otherwise you will be using `O(L-R)` space which might not be optimal.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it is pre-sorted. If not, best case is `O(nlogn)`. My plan was to use the actual vertices. Computing the area will be O(n) once you have constructed a polygon.

Comment: I think I found the optimal algorithm. My implementation is a bit messy, but I think that the algorithm is quite sound. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 7):

You are allocating a separate key-value pair for every single integer value in your range. Imagine the case where `R = 1` and `L = 100000`. Your `items` dictionary will be filled with 1000000 items. Your basic idea of processing/removing overlaps is is sound, but the way you do it is massive overkill.

Like so much else in life, this is a graph problem in disguise. Imaging the vertices being the rectangles you are trying to process and the (weighted) edges being the overlaps. The complication is that you can not just add up the areas of the vertices and subtract the areas of the overlaps, because many of the overlaps overlap each other as well. The overlap issue can be resolved by applying a transformation that converts two overlapping rectangles into non-overlapping rectangles, effectively cutting the edge that connects them. The transformation is shown in the image below. Notice that in some cases one of the vertices will be removed as well, simplifying the graph, while in another case a new vertex is added:

[image]
<sup>Green: overlap to be chopped out.</sup>

Normally, if we have `m` rectangles and `n` overlaps between them, constructing the graph would be an `O(m2)` operation because we would have to check all vertices for overlaps against each other. However, we can bypass a construction of the input graph entirely to get a `O(m + n)` traversal algorithm, which is going to be optimal since we will only analyze each rectangle once, and construct the output graph with no overlaps as efficiently as possible. `O(m + n)` assumes that your input rectangles are sorted according to their left edges in ascending order. If that is not the case, the algorithm will be `O(mlog(m) + n)` to account for the initial sorting step. Note that as the graph density increases, `n` will go from `~m` to `~m2`. This confirms the intuitive idea that the fewer overlaps there are, them more you would expect the process will run in `O(m)` time, while the more overlaps there are, the closer you will run to `O(m2)` time.

The space complexity of the proposed algorithm will be `O(m)`: each rectangle in the input will result in at most two rectangles in the output, and `2m = O(m)`.

Enough about complexity analysis and on to the algorithm itself. The input will be a sequence of rectangles defined by `L`, `R`, `H` as you have now. I will assume that the input is sorted by the leftmost edge `L`. The output graph will be a linked list of rectangles defined by the same parameters, sorted in *descending* order by the *rightmost* edge. The head of the list will be the rightmost rectangle. The output will have no overlaps between any rectangles, so the total area of the skyline will just be the sum of `H * (R - L)` for each of the `~m` output rectangles.

The reason for picking a linked list is that the only two operations we need is iteration from the head node and the cheapest insertion possible to maintain the list in sorted order. The sorting will be done as part of overlap checking, so we do not need to do any kind of binary searches through the list or anything like that.

Since the input list is ordered by increasing left edge and the output list is ordered by decreasing right edge, we can guarantee that each rectangle added will be checked only against the rectangles it actually overlaps<sup>1</sup>. We will do overlap checking and removal as shown in the diagram above until we reach a rectangle whose left edge is less than or equal to the left edge of the new rectangle. All further rectangles in the output list are guaranteed not to overlap with the new rectangle. This check-and-chop operation guarantees that each overlap is visited at most once, and that no non-overlapping rectangles are processed unnecessarily, making the algorithm optimal.

Before I show code, here is a diagram of the algorithm in action. Red rectangles are new rectangles; note that their left edges progress to the right. Blue rectangles are ones that are already added and have overlap with the new rectangle. Black rectangles are already added and have no overlap with the new one. The numbering represents the order of the output list. It is always done from the right. A linked list is a perfect structure to maintain this progression since it allows cheap insertions and replacements:

[image]

Here is an implementation of the algorithm which assumes that the input coordinates are passed in as an iterable of objects having the attributes `l`, `r`, and `h`. The iteration order is assumed to be sorted by the left edge. If that is not the case, apply [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) or [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) to the input first:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# Defined in this order so you can sort a list by left edge without a custom key
Rect = namedtuple('Rect', ['l', 'r', 'h'])

class LinkedList:
    __slots__ = ['value', 'next']

    """
    Implements a singly-linked list with mutable nodes and an iterator.
    """
    def __init__(self, value=None, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Iterate over the *nodes* in the list, starting with this one.

        The `value` and `next` attribute of any node may be modified
        during iteration.
        """
        while self:
            yield self
            self = self.next

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Provided for inspection purposes.

        Works well with `namedtuple` values.
        """
        return ' -> '.join(repr(x.value) for x in self)


def process_skyline(skyline):
    """
    Turns an iterable of rectangles sharing a common baseline into a
    `LinkedList` of rectangles containing no overlaps.

    The input is assumed to be sorted in ascending order by left edge.
    Each element of the input must have the attributes `l`, r`, `h`.

    The output will be sorted in descending order by right edge.

    Return `None` if the input is empty.
    """
    def intersect(r1, r2, default=None):
        """
        Return (1) a flag indicating the order of `r1` and `r2`,
        (2) a linked list of between one and three non-overlapping
        rectangles covering the exact same area as `r1` and `r2`,
        and (3) a pointer to the last nodes (4) a pointer to the
        second-to-last node, or `default` if there is only one node.

        The flag is set to True if the left edge of `r2` is strictly less
        than the left edge of `r1`. That would indicate that the left-most
        (last) chunk of the tuple came from `r2` instead of `r1`. For the
        algorithm as a whole, that means that we need to keep checking for
        overlaps.

        The resulting list is always returned sorted descending by the
        right edge. The input rectangles will not be modified. If they are
        not returned as-is, a `Rect` object will be used instead.
        """
        # Swap so left edge of r1 < left edge of r2
        if r1.l > r2.l:
            r1, r2 = r2, r1
            swapped = True
        else:
            swapped = False

        if r2.l >= r1.r:
            # case 0: no overlap at all
            last = LinkedList(r1)
            s2l = result = LinkedList(r2, last)
        elif r1.r < r2.r:
            # case 1: simple overlap
            if r1.h > r2.h:
                # Chop r2
                r2 = Rect(r1.r, r2.r, r2.h)
            else:
                r1 = Rect(r1.l, r2.l, r1.h)
            last = LinkedList(r1)
            s2l = result = LinkedList(r2, last)
        elif r1.h < r2.h:
            # case 2: split into 3
            r1a = Rect(r1.l, r2.l, r1.h)
            r1b = Rect(r2.r, r1.r, r1.h)
            last = LinkedList(r1a)
            s2l = LinkedList(r2, last)
            result = LinkedList(r1b, s2l)
        else:
            # case 3: complete containment
            result = LinkedList(r1)
            last = result
            s2l = default

        return swapped, result, last, s2l

    root = LinkedList()

    skyline = iter(skyline)
    try:
        # Add the first node as-is
        root.next = LinkedList(next(skyline))
    except StopIteration:
        # Empty input iterator
        return None

    for new_rect in skyline:
        prev = root
        for rect in root.next:
            need_to_continue, replacement, last, second2last = \
                    intersect(rect.value, new_rect, prev)
            # Replace the rectangle with the de-overlapped regions
            prev.next = replacement
            if not need_to_continue:
                # Retain the remainder of the list
                last.next = rect.next
                break
            # Force the iterator to move on to the last node
            new_rect = last.value
            prev = second2last

    return root.next
```

Computing the total area is now trivial:

```
skyline = [
    Rect(-3, 0, 3), Rect(-1, 1, 2), Rect(2, 4, 4),
    Rect(3, 7, 2), Rect(6, 8, 3),
]
processed = process_skyline(skyline)
area = sum((x.value.r - x.value.l) * x.value.h for x in processed) if processed else None
```

Notice the altered order of the input parameters (`h` moved to the end). The resulting `area` is `29`. This matches with what I get by doing the computation by hand. You can also do

```
>>> print(processed)
Rect(l=6, r=8, h=3) -> Rect(l=4, r=6, h=2) -> Rect(l=2, r=4, h=4) ->
Rect(l=0, r=1, h=2) -> Rect(l=-3, r=0, h=3)
```

This is to be expected from the diagram of the inputs/output shown below:

[image]

As an additional verification, I added a new building, `Rect(-4, 9, 1)` to the start of the list. It overlaps all the others and adds three units to `area`, or a final result of `32`. `processed` comes out as:

```
Rect(l=8, r=9, h=1) -> Rect(l=6, r=8, h=3) -> Rect(l=4, r=6, h=2) ->
Rect(l=2, r=4, h=4) -> Rect(l=1, r=2, h=1) -> Rect(l=0, r=1, h=2) ->
Rect(l=-3, r=0, h=3) -> Rect(l=-4, r=-3, h=1)
```

**Note:**

While I am sure that this problem has been solved many times over, the solution I present here is entirely my own work, done without consulting any other references. The idea of using an implicit graph representation and the resulting analysis is inspired by a recent reading of Steven Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual, Second Edition. It is one of the best comp-sci books I have ever come across.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, if a new rectangle does not overlap *any* other rectangles, it will be checked against one rectangle it does not overlap. If that extra check was always the case, the algorithm would have an additional `m - 1` comparisons to do. Fortunately, `m + m + n - 1 = O(m + n)` even if we *always* had to check one extra rectangle (which we don't).