# Efficient unions and intersections in 2D plane when y_min = 0

Tags: python, algorithm

If got the following problem:

Given a series of rectangles defined by {x_min, height and x_max}, I want to efficiently compute their intersection and union, creating a new series.
For instance, if I got S1 = [{1,3,3}] and S2 = [{2,3,5}], the union would result in S3 = [{1,3,5}] and intersection in S3 = [{2,3,3}]. This would be a fairly simple case, but when S1 and S2 are a list of rectangles (unordered) It get's a little bit tricky.

My idea is trying some divide and conquer strategy, like using a modificated mergesort, and in the merge phase try to also merge those buildings. But I'm a little bit unsure about how to express this.
Basically I can't write down how to compare two rectangles with those coordinates and decide if they have to be in S3, or if I have to create a new one (for the intersection).

For the union I think the idea has to be fairly similar, but the negation (i.e. if they don't interesct).

This has to be O(nlogn) for sure, given this is in a 2D plane I surely have to sort it. Currently my first approach is O(n^2).

Any help how to reduce the complexity?

PD: The implementation I'm doing is in Python

Comment: Have you tried sweep line approach?

Comment: they all begin in y = 0?, can rectangles in same series overlap? [{1,3,3}, {2,5,4}]

Comment: They begin y=0 and they cant overlap in the serie

Comment: @MBo I think that with sweep line It is polynomic

Comment: @trigonom they begin y=0 and cant overlap in the serie

Comment: What, in this context, is the union of {0, 1, 2} and {1, 2, 2} ? Using the normal idea of 'union', it seems like a shape than can't be represented using the model at hand.

Comment: Hang on. I've answered this exact thing before

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter It woud be something like S3 = [{0,1,1}, {1,2,2}]. Or another representation, this one is not unique

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47293793/2988730? Specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47324760/2988730?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write the whole thing out in psudo-code, and found that it was too psudo-y to be useful and too code-y to be readable. Here's the basic idea:

You can sort each of your input lists in O(n*log(n)).

Because we assume there's no overlap within each series, we can now replace each of those lists with lists of the form {start, height}. **We can drop the "end" attribute by having a height-0 element start where the last element should have ended**. (or not, if two elements were already abutting.)

Now you can walk/recurse/pop your way through both lists in a single pass, building a new list of {start, height} outputs as you go. I see no reason you couldn't be building both your union and intersection lists at the same time.

Cleanup (conversion to a minimal representation in the original format) will be another pass, but still O(n).

So the problem is O(n*log(n)), and could be O(n) if you could finagle a way to get your input pre-sorted.