# Linked List Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __len__(self):
        cur = self.head
        count = 0
        while cur is not None:
            count += 1
            cur = cur.next
        return count

    def append(self, item):
        cur = self.head
        while cur is not None:
            cur = cur.next
        cur.next = ?
```

I am trying to append to the linkedlist but I cant use 'cur.next' as cur has no attribute 'next'. Any hints on this?

Thanks!

My test cases:

```
def test_append_empty() -> None:
    lst = LinkedList()
    lst.append(1)
    assert lst.head.data == 1


def test_append_one() -> None:
    lst = LinkedList()
    lst.head = Node(1)
    lst.append(2)
    assert lst.head.next.data == 2
```

Comment: You have to create an element anyway.there's a special case for `self.head == None`.  assign it to `self.head` if it's None

Comment: This is not valid python code

Comment: @MadPhysicist are you talking about OP?

Comment: @PatrickArtner oh i edited OP. sorry!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280243/python-linked-list

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for the case when `self.head` is `None` as Nonetype will have no attribute next. Also iterate till you find the next pointer in the node to be None. So it should be `cur.next is not None` rather than `cur is None` which is finding if the Node is None. Logically speaking you cannot append anything to `None`

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __len__(self):
        if not self.head:
            return 0
        cur = self.head
        count = 0
        while cur is not None:
            count += 1
            cur = cur.next
        return count

    def append(self, item):
        if not self.head:
            self.head=Node(item)
            return
        cur = self.head
        while cur.next is not None:
            cur = cur.next
        cur.next = Node(item)
```

Test case1

```
l=LinkedList()
l.append(1)
l.__len__() #prints 1
```

Test case2

```
l=LinkedList()
l.append(2)
l.append(3)
l.__len__() #2

temp=l.head
while(temp):
    print(temp.data)
    temp=temp.next
```

Including testcases of OP as well

```
def test_append_empty():
    lst = LinkedList()
    lst.append(1)
    print(lst.head.data == 1)


def test_append_one():
    lst = LinkedList()
    lst.head = Node(1)
    lst.append(2)
    print(lst.head.next.data == 2)

test_append_empty() #True
test_append_one() #True
```

Comment: Dont you think there will be an attribute error on the last line?

Comment: I just have. I got a AttributeError!

Comment: @Kaisr it is hard to believe that. I might have edited my answer since you had executed it. As I have run the testcases and it works just fine for me. If not please include the full stacktrace

Comment: can i send you the whole code without edits via email. I have my own testcases too

Comment: No, please post here. Will be beneficial for others as well. As I cannot see any errors executing the above code.

Comment: The len() member is not correct, len(empty_list) should return 0, not -1

Answer (score 0):

I hope that with the clear example of mad_ you have understood the idea that you still have this concept of nodes to handle.

A linked list not only is a list of values, but also a list of links.

Since you seemed interested to do it in one class, here is a quick implementation:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, item=None):
        self.next = None
        self.val = item

    def __len__(self):
        cur = self
        count = 1 if self.val is not None else 0
        while cur.next is not None:
            count += 1
            cur = cur.next
        return count    

    def append(self, item):
        if not self.val:
            self.val = item
            return

        cur = self
        while cur.next is not None:
            cur = cur.next
        cur.next = LinkedList(item)
```

Edit:

Since you've included mad_'s **len**() member to your question, I also added the one adapted for this class.

And here are some usage examples:

```
myList = LinkedList()
myList.append('a')
myList.append('b')
myList.append('c')
myList.append('d')
print(len(myList))
```

Comment: I dont have a self.val in my LinkedList class so I cant relate :(

Comment: The val is actually the value of each node:
myList.val == 'a', myList.next.val == 'b' ... Wether it is by having a seperate node class or by having it directly in the LinkedList class, you need a val member, you can call it data or item or whatever you like!

Comment: nvm I fixed it without changing class documentation